# Webscraping using Python Beautifulsoup loop through HTML tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am web scraping from the following URL 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2013_injuries.htm' using Python Beautifulsoup.
From the URL I want to scrape the players name, their injury and the week of the injury.
I can scrape the information from week 1 which displays the following outcome:

```
[['Danny Amendola'], 'Questionable: hamstring', 'week_1']
[['Armond Armstead'], 'Out: infection', 'week_1']
[['Kyle Arrington'], 'NA', 'week_1']
[['Brandon Bolden'], 'Questionable: knee', 'week_1']
... and so on for all the week 1 injuries.
```

But once all of the week 1 injuries are displayed it stops.

I want the outcome to be able to run straight into week 2, week 3, week 4 ...etc.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2013_injuries.htm'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.find("tbody")
head = page_soup.find("thead")


player = containers.find_all("tr")

for tr in player:
    th = tr.find_all("th")
    name = [i.text for i in th]

    week = tr.td["data-stat"]

    try:
        injury = tr.td["data-tip"]
        print([name, injury, week])
    except KeyError:
        injury = "NA"
        print([name, injury, week])
```

The outcome I am looking for is for the code to print the players name, their injury and the week of the injury for all the weeks displayed in the table from the URL.
For example, once all the week 1 injuries are printed, I want it to display all the week 2 and week 3 injuries and so on..
So it would look something like this:

```
[['Adrian Wilson'], 'Injured Reserve: hamstring', 'week_1']
[['Tavon Wilson'], 'NA', 'week_1']
[['Markus Zusevics'], 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed', 'week_1']
[['Danny Amendola'], 'Questionable: groin', 'week_2']
...
```

Comment: Can you show the output of week i.e print(week)? I am thinking that you are only iterating over the first instance of the data-tip and not storing week_2, week_3, etc.

Comment: @Kevin. If you go back to your first question a few hours ago, I provided the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are only iterating over the first instance of the data-tip, this should work:

```
player = containers.find_all("tr")
for tr in player:
   th = tr.find_all("th")
   name = [i.text for i in th]
   for td in tr.findAll('td'): 
       week = td["data-stat"]
       try:
           injury = td["data-tip"]
           print([name, injury, week])
       except KeyError:
           injury = "NA"
           print([name, injury, week])
```

Comment: Not fully working it is looping through now but its just displaying the players name, their injury and injury date for week 1 18 times now for each player instead of progressing to week 2, week 3... etc. So it is correct to some extent as it goes up to week 18 but it is just repeating week 1 instead of progressing to week 2..

Comment: @Kevin in case you missed the message, go back to your question from earlier today. I posted the code to get all weeks there.

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2013_injuries.htm'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.find("tbody")
head = page_soup.find("thead")


player = containers.find_all("tr")

weeks = head.find_all('th')
week_list = [i['data-stat'] for i in weeks][1:]

for week in week_list:
    for tr in player:
        th = tr.find_all("th")
        name = [i.text for i in th]

        td = tr.find('td', {'data-stat':week})
        week = td["data-stat"]

        try:
            injury = td["data-tip"]
            print([name, injury, week])
        except KeyError:
            injury = "NA"
            print([name, injury, week])
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2013_injuries.htm').text
overall = []
page_soup = soup(html, 'html.parser')
containers = page_soup.find('tbody')
players = containers.find_all('tr')
for player in players:
    th = player.find_all('th')
    name = [i.text for i in th]
    tds = player.find_all('td', {'class': re.compile('^center poptip')})
    weeklyInjuries = ', '.join([', '.join(i) for i in [list(a) for a in zip([i['data-tip'] for i in tds], [i['data-stat'] for i in tds])]])
    if len(weeklyInjuries) == 0:
        weeklyInjuries = 'N/A'
    print([name, weeklyInjuries])
```

Output:

```
[['Danny Amendola'], 'Questionable: hamstring, week_1, Questionable: groin, week_2, Doubtful: groin, week_3, Questionable: groin, week_4, Questionable: groin, week_5, Probable: groin, week_6, Out: concussion, week_7, Questionable: concussion, week_8, Questionable: groin, week_9, Probable: groin, week_11, Probable: groin, week_12, Probable: groin, week_13, Probable: groin, week_14, Probable: groin, week_15, Questionable: groin, week_16, Probable: groin, week_17']
[['Armond Armstead'], 'Out: infection, week_1, Out: infection, week_2, Out: infection, week_3, Out: infection, week_4, Out: infection, week_5, Out: infection, week_6, Out: infection, week_7, Out: infection, week_8, Out: infection, week_9, Out: infection, week_11, Out: infection, week_12, Out: infection, week_13, Out: infection, week_14, Out: infection, week_15, Out: infection, week_16, Out: infection, week_17, Out: infection, week_19, Out: infection, week_20']
[['Kyle Arrington'], 'Questionable: groin, week_4, Questionable: groin, week_5, Probable: groin, week_6, Probable: groin, week_7, Probable: groin, week_8, Questionable: groin, week_9, Questionable: groin, week_11, Probable: groin, week_12, Questionable: groin, week_13, Questionable: groin, week_14, Questionable: groin, week_15, Questionable: groin, week_16, Questionable: groin, week_17']
[['Brandon Bolden'], 'Questionable: knee, week_1, Questionable: knee, week_2, Questionable: knee, week_3, Questionable: knee, week_4, Questionable: knee, week_5, Probable: knee, week_6, Questionable: knee, week_7, Questionable: knee, week_8, Questionable: knee, week_9, Questionable: knee, week_11']
[['Josh Boyce'], 'Doubtful: hip, week_16, Questionable: hip, week_17']
[['Tom Brady'], 'Probable: right shoulder, week_8, Probable: right shoulder, week_9, Probable: right shoulder, week_11, Probable: right shoulder, week_12, Probable: shoulder, week_13, Probable: right shoulder, week_14, Questionable: shoulder, week_15, Probable: right shoulder, week_16, Probable: right shoulder, week_17']
[['Marcus Cannon'], 'Questionable: shoulder, week_7, Questionable: shoulder, week_8, Questionable: shoulder, week_9, Questionable: ankle, week_13, Questionable: ankle, week_14, Questionable: ankle, week_15, Questionable: ankle, week_16, Questionable: ankle, week_17']
[['Marquice Cole'], 'Probable: hamstring, week_2, Questionable: hamstring, week_4, Questionable: hamstring, week_5, Questionable: leg, week_13, Questionable: shin, week_14, Questionable: shin, week_15']
[['Austin Collie'], 'N/A']
[['Dan Connolly'], 'Questionable: finger, week_3, Questionable: head, week_7']
[['Alfonzo Dennard'], 'Probable: ankle, week_2, Questionable: leg, week_11, Questionable: knee, week_13, Questionable: knee, week_14, Questionable: knee/shoulder, week_15, Questionable: knee/shoulder, week_16, Questionable: knee/shoulder, week_17']
[['Aaron Dobson'], 'Questionable: hamstring, week_1, Questionable: hamstring, week_2, Doubtful: shoulder, week_4, Questionable: neck, week_5, Questionable: neck, week_6, Questionable: undisclosed, week_13, Questionable: foot, week_14, Questionable: foot, week_15, Questionable: foot, week_16, Questionable: foot, week_17']
[['Nate Ebner'], 'Questionable: ankle, week_1, Questionable: ankle, week_2, Questionable: ankle, week_3, Questionable: ankle, week_4, Questionable: ankle, week_5, Probable: ankle, week_6']
[['Julian Edelman'], 'Questionable: thigh, week_7, Questionable: thigh, week_8, Probable: thigh, week_9']
[['Dane Fletcher'], 'Questionable: groin, week_16, Questionable: groin, week_17']
[['Tyronne Green'], 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_1, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_2, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_3, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_4, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_5, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_6, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_7, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_8, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_9, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_11, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_12, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_13, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_14, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_15, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_16, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_17, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_19, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_20']
[['Steve Gregory'], 'Out: thumb, week_11, Questionable: finger, week_12, Questionable: finger, week_13, Questionable: finger, week_14, Questionable: finger, week_15, Questionable: finger, week_16, Questionable: knee/finger, week_17']
[['Cory Grissom'], 'Injured Reserve: knee, week_1, Injured Reserve: knee, week_2, Injured Reserve: knee, week_3, Injured Reserve: knee, week_4, Injured Reserve: knee, week_5, Injured Reserve: knee, week_6, Injured Reserve: knee, week_7, Injured Reserve: knee, week_8, Injured Reserve: knee, week_9, Injured Reserve: knee, week_11, Injured Reserve: knee, week_12, Injured Reserve: knee, week_13, Injured Reserve: knee, week_14, Injured Reserve: knee, week_15, Injured Reserve: knee, week_16, Injured Reserve: knee, week_17, Injured Reserve: knee, week_19, Injured Reserve: knee, week_20']
[['Rob Gronkowski'], 'Doubtful: arm/back, week_1, Questionable: arm/back, week_2, Doubtful: arm/back, week_3, Questionable: arm/back, week_4, Doubtful: arm/back, week_5, Probable: arm/back, week_6, Questionable: arm/back, week_7, Probable: back/forearm, week_8, Probable: back/forearm/hamstring, week_9, Probable: back/forearm/hamstring, week_11, Probable: back/forearm/hamstring, week_12, Probable: hamstring, week_13, Questionable: ankle, week_14, Injured Reserve: torn right ACL/MCL, week_15, Injured Reserve: torn right ACL/MCL, week_16, Injured Reserve: torn right ACL/MCL, week_17, Injured Reserve: torn right ACL/MCL, week_19, Injured Reserve: torn right ACL/MCL, week_20']
[['Duron Harmon'], 'Questionable: hamstring, week_1, Questionable: hamstring, week_2']
[['Mark Harrison'], 'Out: foot, week_1, Out: foot, week_2, Out: foot, week_3, Out: foot, week_4, Out: foot, week_5, Out: foot, week_6, Out: foot, week_7, Out: foot, week_8, Out: foot, week_9, Out: foot, week_11, Out: foot, week_12, Out: foot, week_13, Out: foot, week_14, Out: foot, week_15, Out: foot, week_16, Out: foot, week_17, Out: foot, week_19, Out: foot, week_20']
[["Dont'a Hightower"], 'Questionable: knee, week_5, Probable: knee, week_6']
[['Michael Hoomanawanui'], 'Questionable: knee, week_7, Questionable: knee, week_8, Questionable: knee, week_9, Questionable: knee, week_12, Questionable: knee, week_13, Probable: knee, week_14, Questionable: knee, week_15, Questionable: knee, week_16, Probable: knee, week_17']
[['Tommy Kelly'], 'Questionable: knee, week_6, Questionable: knee, week_7, Questionable: knee, week_8, Questionable: knee, week_9, Injured Reserve: knee, week_11, Injured Reserve: knee, week_12, Injured Reserve: knee, week_13, Injured Reserve: knee, week_14, Injured Reserve: knee, week_15, Injured Reserve: knee, week_16, Injured Reserve: knee, week_17, Injured Reserve: knee, week_19, Injured Reserve: knee, week_20']
[['Jerod Mayo'], 'Questionable: ankle, week_4, Questionable: ankle, week_5, Probable: ankle, week_6, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_7, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_8, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_9, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_11, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_12, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_13, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_14, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_15, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_16, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_17, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_19, Injured Reserve: shoulder, week_20']
[['Devin McCourty'], 'Questionable: shoulder, week_7, Probable: shoulder, week_8, Questionable: head, week_17']
[['T.J. Moe'], 'Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_1, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_2, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_3, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_4, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_5, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_6, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_7, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_8, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_9, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_11, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_12, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_13, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_14, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_15, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_16, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_17, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_19, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_20']
[['Rob Ninkovich'], 'Probable: groin, week_6, Probable: groin, week_7, Probable: groin, week_8, Questionable: foot, week_11, Questionable: ankle, week_17']
[['Stevan Ridley'], 'Probable: shoulder, week_2, Questionable: knee, week_5, Questionable: knee, week_6']
[['Matt Slater'], 'Questionable: knee, week_2, Out: wrist, week_3, Out: wrist, week_4, Out: wrist, week_5, Out: wrist, week_6, Questionable: wrist, week_8, Probable: wrist, week_9, Probable: wrist, week_11, Probable: wrist, week_12, Probable: wrist, week_13, Probable: right shoulder, week_14, Probable: wrist, week_15']
[['Nate Solder'], 'Probable: back, week_7, Questionable: concussion, week_15, Questionable: concussion, week_16, Questionable: concussion, week_17']
[['Brandon Spikes'], 'Questionable: knee, week_12, Probable: knee, week_13, Questionable: knee, week_14, Questionable: knee, week_15, Questionable: knee, week_16, Questionable: knee, week_17']
[['Zach Sudfeld'], 'Questionable: hamstring, week_2, Probable: hamstring, week_3, Probable: hamstring, week_4, Questionable: hamstring, week_5']
[['Will Svitek'], 'Questionable: knee, week_1, Questionable: knee, week_2, Questionable: knee, week_3, Questionable: knee, week_4, Questionable: knee, week_5, Questionable: ankle, week_14, Questionable: ankle, week_15, Questionable: ankle, week_16, Questionable: ankle, week_17']
[['Aqib Talib'], 'Questionable: hip, week_6, Questionable: hip, week_7, Questionable: hip, week_8, Questionable: hip, week_9, Questionable: hip, week_11, Questionable: hip, week_12, Questionable: hip, week_13, Questionable: hip, week_14, Questionable: hip, week_15, Questionable: hip, week_16, Probable: hip, week_17']
[['Kenbrell Thompkins'], 'Questionable: shoulder, week_5, Questionable: hip, week_14, Questionable: hip, week_15, Questionable: hip, week_16, Questionable: hip, week_17']
[['Shane Vereen'], 'Out: wrist, week_2, Injured Reserve: wrist, week_3, Injured Reserve: wrist, week_4, Injured Reserve: wrist, week_5, Injured Reserve: wrist, week_6, Injured Reserve: wrist, week_7, Injured Reserve: wrist, week_8, Injured Reserve: wrist, week_9, Injured Reserve: wrist, week_11, Probable: wrist, week_12, Probable: wrist, week_13, Probable: wrist, week_14, Probable: wrist, week_15, Questionable: groin, week_16, Probable: groin, week_17']
[['Sebastian Vollmer'], 'Questionable: foot, week_4, Questionable: foot, week_5, Injured Reserve: leg, week_9, Injured Reserve: leg, week_11, Injured Reserve: leg, week_12, Injured Reserve: leg, week_13, Injured Reserve: leg, week_14, Injured Reserve: leg, week_15, Injured Reserve: leg, week_16, Injured Reserve: leg, week_17, Injured Reserve: leg, week_19, Injured Reserve: leg, week_20']
[['Leon Washington'], 'Questionable: thigh, week_2, Questionable: thigh, week_3, Questionable: thigh, week_4, Questionable: thigh, week_5, Questionable: ankle, week_6, Questionable: ankle, week_7, Questionable: ankle, week_8, Questionable: ankle, week_9, Questionable: ankle, week_11, Questionable: ankle, week_12']
[['Ryan Wendell'], 'Questionable: concussion, week_6']
[['Chris White'], 'Questionable: back, week_13']
[['Vince Wilfork'], 'Probable: foot, week_4, Out: Achilles, week_5, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_6, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_7, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_8, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_9, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_11, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_12, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_13, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_14, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_15, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_16, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_17, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_19, Injured Reserve: Achilles, week_20']
[['Adrian Wilson'], 'Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_1, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_2, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_3, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_4, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_5, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_6, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_7, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_8, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_9, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_11, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_12, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_13, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_14, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_15, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_16, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_17, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_19, Injured Reserve: hamstring, week_20']
[['Tavon Wilson'], 'Questionable: hamstring, week_5, Questionable: hamstring, week_6, Questionable: hamstring, week_7, Questionable: hamstring, week_8, Questionable: hamstring, week_9']
[['Markus Zusevics'], 'Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_1, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_2, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_3, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_4, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_5, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_6, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_7, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_8, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_9, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_11, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_12, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_13, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_14, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_15, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_16, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_17, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_19, Injured Reserve: undisclosed, week_20']
```